# Need to Transform a Rows of Data into a single Row

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have a set of Data in MS Access

```
Number Owner
 1      Heelo
 1      Hi
 1      There
 2      What
 2      Up
```

This needs to be transferrid into

```
Number Owner1 Owner2 Owner3 Owner4
1      Heelo  Hi     There    -
2      What   Up       -      -
```

Any idea on how to go on with this?

The crux in this case is we don't have a third column from where we can pivot the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to transpose row pairs to columns in MS ACCESS database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736317/sql-to-transpose-row-pairs-to-columns-in-ms-access-database)

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a third column with a sequence of numbers:

`SELECT Number, (select count(*) 
                 from YourTable as s 
                 where s.number = t.number) as sequence, owner
from YourTable as t`

then apply this solution to the results: [SQL to transpose row pairs to columns in MS ACCESS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736317/sql-to-transpose-row-pairs-to-columns-in-ms-access-database)