# Transpose to Count columns of Boolean values on Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, boolean, transpose

Ok, so I have a Student table that has 6 fields, (StudentID, HasBamboo, HasFlower, HasAloe, HasFern, HasCactus) the "HasPlant" fields are boolean, so 1 for having the plant, 0 for not having the plant.

I want to find the average number of plants that a student has. There are hundreds of students in the table. I know this could involve transposing of some sort and of course counting the boolean values and getting an average. I did look at this question [SQL to transpose row pairs to columns in MS ACCESS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736317/sql-to-transpose-row-pairs-to-columns-in-ms-access-database) for information on Transposing (never done it before), but I'm thinking there would be too many columns perhaps.

My first thought was using a for loop, but I'm not sure those exist in SQL in Access. Maybe a SELECT/FROM/WHERE/IN type structure?

Just hints on the logic and some possible reading material would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just get individual totals per category:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENTS WHERE HasBamboo
```

add them all up, and divide by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENTS
```

It's not a great database design though... Better normalized would be:

```
Table Students; fields StudentID, StudentName
Table Plants; fields PlantID, PlantName
Table OwnedPlants; fields StudentID,PlantID
```

The last table then stores records for each student that owns a particular plant; but you could easily add different information at the right place (appartment number to Students; Latin name to Plants; date aquired to OwnedPlants) without completely redesigning table structure and add lots of fields. (DatAquiredBamboo, DateAquiredFlower, etc etc)

Comment: Oh and your average plant problem could simply be solved by total count of OwnedPlants divided by total count of Students...

Comment: Thanks! I ended up making a long list of left joins to get the total count before just stopping. I'll look more into your solution. I agree that the design isn't pretty or great haha.